# Create the equivalent of a ConnectableSubject in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I need to create the equivalent of a ConnectableSubject in RxJava. I'd like to publish events to a subject before anything has subscribed to it and I want the subscriber to get all of the events. I don't want to use a ReplaySubject to cache these events, because I don't want to keep them in memory after they have been consumed.

Ideally this code would work, but the first event is lost.

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
ConnectableObservable<String> observable = subject.publish();

subject.onNext("1");
observable.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(String s) {
        System.out.println("string is " + s);
    }
});
observable.connect();
subject.onNext("2");
subject.onNext("3");
```

The output of this code is

```
string is 2
string is 3
```

Ideally it should be

```
string is 1
string is 2
string is 3
```

Comment: A [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) is close to what you're looking for, but appears to cache input indefinitely for _all_ future subscribers (rather than the _first_ subscriber). There are some options though - [`createWithSize(int size)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html#createWithSize(int)) allows you to specify a max cache size.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `publish()` on a `PublishSubject` is functionally a no-op. The closest thing you need is the internal `BufferUntilSubscriber` which buffers events until a single `Subscriber` subscribes to it. However, it doesn't support backpressure or more than one `Subscriber` so you may still need to use `publish()` or `onBackpressureBuffer()`.